# Partial Differential Calcuration

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

$f:R^2 \rightarrow R,\\f(x,y)=\exp(x^2+xy+y^2)$

$D_1:=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}$, $D_2:=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}$

Can I calcurate
$D_1D_2f(0,0):= \dfrac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}(0,0)$ ?

$D_1D_2f(0,0)
=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{D_2f(0+h,0)-D_2f(0,0)}{h}
$

So, I have to calcurate $D_2f(0+h,0)$ and $D_2f(0,0)$.

$D_2f(0+h,0)\\
=\lim_{k \to 0} \dfrac{f(0+h,0+k)-f(0+h,0)}{k}\\
=\lim_{k \to 0} \dfrac{\exp(h^2+hk+k^2)-\exp(h^2)}{k}$

I cannot calcurate this limit.
I would like you to give me hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac {e^{h^{2}+hk+k^{2}}-e^{h^{2}}} k=e^{h^{2}} \frac {1+hk+h^{2}k^{2}+o(k^{2})} k \to he^{h^{2}}$. [I have used the fact that $e^{x}=1+x+o(x^{2})$ as $x \to 0$].

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* Write that as $$e^{h^2}\frac{\left(e^{hk+k^2}-1\right)}{k},$$ and use the identity $$e^y=1+y+y^2/2+y^3/6+\cdots,$$ where $y=hk+k^2.$ You need not go beyond the linear term.